# Java class representation of financial institution?

Tags: java, banking

Would like to know if there's any opensource library that has a class representation of how a generic financial institution ought to be represented?

Of the top of my head, I guess it should at least include a SWIFT code, location properties.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like [Java CAPS](http://developers.sun.com/docs/javacaps/designing/capsswftintprj.ahcbu.html)?

Comment: actually, this defines the format of messages that are passed around between institutions, which is defined by the Swift MT formats. But what I'm looking for is a generic class definition for financial institutions themselves as entities. Thanks anyway!